# How can I speed up these dataframe operations on 12k files/50gb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

#### Background:

I have 12,000 csv files (50gb) of data that mostly have the same format, but some may be missing a column or two and some header rows may not always start on the first row of the file.

I have a class with a couple of functions that utilize `pandas` to analyze and normalize these csv files either stored locally or from a google bucket.

The following actions occur in these functions:

**In `analyze_files`**

- loop through all the files, "peeking" at their contents to determine the headers and if any rows need to be skipped in order to get to the headers row.
- translate all collected headers into a standard format, removing all but alphanumeric and underscores from the filenames.

**In `normalize_files`**

- loop through all files, loading each one completely this time.
- convert the column headers to the standardizwd versions of the headers from `analyze_files`.
- upload or save the updated version of the file

The functions work as-intended. But, I'm looking for methods I could use to speed things up.
Using the below version (simplified into a mvce) with 12,000 local files (8-core 16gb ram)

- `analyze_files` takes around 2-4 minutes
- `normalize_files` takes around 52 minutes

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import re

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "./service_account_details.json"


class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, uses_gs=False, gs_bucket_name=None, gs_folder_path=None):
        self.__uses_gs = uses_gs
        if uses_gs:
            self.__gs_client = storage.Client()
            self.__gs_bucket_name = gs_bucket_name
            self.__gs_bucket = self.__gs_client.get_bucket(gs_bucket_name)
            self.__gs_folder_path = gs_folder_path
        else:
            # save to a subfolder of current directory
            self.__save_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), self.__name__)
            if not os.path.exists(self.__save_location):
                os.mkdir(self.__save_location)
        self.__file_analysis = dict()
        self.__file_columns = set()
        self.__file_column_mapping = dict()
    
    def analyze_files(self):
        # collect the list of files
        files_to_analyze = list()
        if self.__uses_gs:
            gs_files = self.__gs_client.list_blobs(self.__gs_bucket, prefix=self.__gs_folder_path, delimiter="/")
            for file in gs_files:
                if file.name == self.__gs_folder_path:
                    continue
                gs_filepath = f"gs://{self._gs_bucket_name}/{file.name}"
                files_to_analyze.append(gs_filepath)
        else:
            local_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.__save_location, "*.csv"))
            files_to_analyze.extend(local_files)
                
        # analyze each collected file
        for filepath in files_to_analyze:
            # determine how many rows to skip in order to start at the header row,
            # then collect the headers for this particular file, to be utilized for comparisons in `normalize_files`
            skiprows = None
            while True:
                try:
                    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
                    break
                except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
                    try:
                        start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                        skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
                    except IndexError:
                        print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                        continue
            headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
            self.__file_columns.update(headers)
            # store file details as pandas parameters, so we can smoothly transition into reading the files efficiently
            skiprows = skiprows + 1 if skiprows else 1  # now that we know the headers, we can skip the header row
            self.__file_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
            
        # convert the columns to their bigquery-compliant equivalents
        non_alpha = re.compile(r"([\s\W]|^\d+)")
        multi_under = re.compile(r"(_{2,})")
        self.__file_column_mapping.update({
            file_column: multi_under.sub("_", non_alpha.sub("_", file_column)).upper()
            for file_column in self.__file_columns
        })

    def normalize_files(self):
        # perform the normalizations and upload/save the final results
        total_columns = len(self.__file_columns)
        for filepath, params in self.__file_analysis.items():
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath, **params)
            # rename the column header to align with bigquery columns
            df.rename(columns=self.__file_column_mapping, inplace=True)
 
            if len(params["names"]) != total_columns:
                # swap the missing column names out for the bigquery equivalents
                missing_columns = [self.__file_column_mapping[c] for c in self.__file_columns - set(params["names"])]
                # add the missing columns to the dataframe
                df[[*missing_columns]] = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(missing_columns)], index=df.index)
 
            if self.__uses_gs:
                blob_path = filepath[5 + len(self.__gs_bucket_name) + 1:]  # "gs://" + "{bucket_name}" + "/"
                self.__gs_bucket.blob(blob_path).upload_from_string(df.to_csv(index=False), "text/csv")
            else:  # save locally
                df.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

I thought about using `dask`, combined with `ProcessPool` and `ThreadPool` from the `multiprocessing` module. But, I am struggling with exactly what approach to take.

Since the dataframe operations are CPU-Bound they seem best-suited for `dask`, possibly combined with a `ProcessPool` to divvy up the 12k files across the 8 available cores, then `dask` would utilize the threads of each core (overcoming GIL limitations).

The uploading of the files back to disk or a google bucket seem more suited for a `ThreadPool`, since that activity is Network-bound.

As for reading in files from a Google bucket, I'm not sure what approach would work best.

Basically, it comes down to two sceneries:

1. What methods/logic would perform best when working with local files?
2. And what methods/logic would perform best when pulling from and saving back to (overwriting/updating) a Google bucket?

Can someone please provide some direction or code that will provide the most efficient speed boost for the above two functions?

Benchmark tests would be greatly appreciated as I've been pondering this topic for the better part of a week and it would be great to have statistics to back-up the decision of methodology.

## Current Benchmarks from what I've tried

```py
def local_analysis_test_dir_pd(test_dir):
    file_analysis, file_columns = dict(), set()
    local_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(test_dir, "*.csv"))
    for filepath in local_files:
        skiprows = None
        while True:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
                break
            except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
                try:
                    start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                    skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
                except IndexError:
                    print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                    continue
        headers = df.columns.values.tolist()  # noqa
        skiprows = skiprows + 1 if skiprows else 1
        file_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
        file_columns.update(headers)

    non_alpha = re.compile(r"([\s\W]|^\d+)")
    multi_under = re.compile(r"(_{2,})")
    file_column_mapping = {
        file_column: multi_under.sub(" ", non_alpha.sub("_", file_column)).upper()
        for file_column in file_columns
    }
    # print dictionary length for sanity check; to ensure both functions are performing identical actions.
    print("['local_analysis_test_dir_pd'] result:", len(file_analysis), len(file_columns))
    return file_analysis, file_columns, file_column_mapping

def local_analysis_test_dir_dd(test_dir):
    file_analysis, file_columns = dict(), set()
    local_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(test_dir, "*.csv"))
    
    def dask_worker(filepath):
        siloed_analysis, siloed_columns = dict(), set()
        skiprows = None
        while True:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
                break
            except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
                try:
                    start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                    skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
                except IndexError:
                    print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                    return siloed_analysis, siloed_columns
        headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
        siloed_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
        siloed_columns.update(headers)
        return siloed_analysis, siloed_columns
    
    dask_futures = [dask.delayed(dask_worker)(filepath) for filepath in local_files]
    file_analyses, column_sets = map(list, zip(*list(dask.compute(*dask_futures))))
    for analysis in file_analyses:
        file_analysis.update(analysis)
    file_columns.update(*column_sets)
    non_alpha = re.compile(r"([\s\W]|^\d+)")
    multi_under = re.compile(r"(_{2,})")
    file_column_mapping = {
        file_column: multi_under.sub(" ", non_alpha.sub("_", file_column)).upper()
        for file_column in file_columns
    }
    # print dictionary length for sanity check; to ensure both functions are performing identical actions.
    print("['local_analysis_test_dir_dd'] result:", len(file_analysis), len(file_columns))

def remote_analysis_test_dir_pd(test_dir):
    remote_files, file_analysis, file_columns = list(), dict(), set()
    prefix = test_dir.replace("gs://webscraping/", "") + "/"
    gs_files = gs_client.list_blobs("webscraping", prefix=prefix, delimiter="/")
    for file in gs_files:
        if file.name == prefix:
            continue
        elif file.name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            continue
        elif not file.name.endswith(".csv"):
            continue
        gs_filepath = f"gs://webscraping/{file.name}"
        remote_files.append(gs_filepath)

    for filepath in remote_files:
        skiprows = None
        while True:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
                break
            except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
                try:
                    start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                    skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
                except IndexError:
                    print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                    continue
        headers = df.columns.values.tolist()  # noqa
        skiprows = skiprows + 1 if skiprows else 1
        file_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
        file_columns.update(headers)

    non_alpha = re.compile(r"([\s\W]|^\d+)")
    multi_under = re.compile(r"(_{2,})")
    file_column_mapping = {
        file_column: multi_under.sub("_", non_alpha.sub("_", file_column)).upper()
        for file_column in file_columns
    }
    # print dictionary length for sanity check; to ensure both functions are performing identical actions.
    print("['remote_analysis_test_dir_pd'] result:", len(file_analysis), len(file_columns))
    return file_analysis, file_columns, file_column_mapping

def remote_analysis_test_dir_dd(test_dir):
    remote_files, file_analysis, file_columns = list(), dict(), set()
    prefix = test_dir.replace("gs://webscraping/", "") + "/"
    gs_files = gs_client.list_blobs("webscraping", prefix=prefix, delimiter="/")
    for file in gs_files:
        if file.name == prefix:
            continue
        elif file.name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            continue
        elif not file.name.endswith(".csv"):
            continue
        gs_filepath = f"gs://webscraping/{file.name}"
        remote_files.append(gs_filepath)

    def dask_worker(filepath):
        siloed_analysis, siloed_columns = dict(), set()
        skiprows = None
        while True:
            try:
                df = pd.read_csv(filepath, nrows=nrows, skiprows=skiprows)
                break
            except pd.errors.ParserError as e:
                try:
                    start_row_index = re.findall(r"Expected \d+ fields in line (\d+), saw \d+", str(e))[0]
                    skiprows = int(start_row_index) - 1
                except IndexError:
                    print("Could not locate start_row_index in pandas ParserError message")
                    return siloed_analysis, siloed_columns
        headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
        siloed_analysis[filepath] = dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))
        siloed_columns.update(headers)
        return siloed_analysis, siloed_columns

    dask_futures = [dask.delayed(dask_worker)(filepath) for filepath in remote_files]
    file_analyses, column_sets = map(list, zip(*list(dask.compute(*dask_futures))))
    for analysis in file_analyses:
        file_analysis.update(analysis)
    file_columns.update(*column_sets)
    non_alpha = re.compile(r"([\s\W]|^\d+)")
    multi_under = re.compile(r"(_{2,})")
    file_column_mapping = {
        file_column: multi_under.sub("_", non_alpha.sub("_", file_column)).upper()
        for file_column in file_columns
    }
    # print dictionary length for sanity check; to ensure both functions are performing identical actions.
    print("['remote_analysis_test_dir_dd'] result:", len(file_analysis), len(file_columns))
    return file_analysis, file_columns, file_column_mapping

def normalization_plain_with_pd(file_analysis, file_columns, file_column_mapping, meta_columns):
    total_columns = len(file_columns)
    for filepath, params in file_analysis.items():
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, **params)
        # rename the column header to align with bigquery columns
        df.rename(columns=file_column_mapping, inplace=True)
        if len(params["names"]) != total_columns:
            missing_columns = [file_column_mapping[c] for c in file_columns - set(params["names"])]
            # add the missing columns to the dataframe
            df[[*missing_columns]] = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(missing_columns)], index=df.index)
        fpath, fname = os.path.split(filepath)
        if not fpath.startswith("gs://"):
            updated_path = os.path.join(fpath, "normalized_with_pd")
            if not os.path.exists(updated_path):
                os.mkdir(updated_path)
            new_path = os.path.join(updated_path, fname)
        else:
            new_path = "/".join([fpath, "normalized_with_pd", fname])
        df.to_csv(new_path, index=False)

def normalization_plain_with_dd(file_analysis, _file_columns, _file_column_mapping, _meta_columns):
    def dask_worker(file_item, file_columns, file_column_mapping, meta_columns):
        total_columns = len(file_columns)
        filepath, params = file_item
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath, **params)
        # rename the column header to align with bigquery columns
        df.rename(columns=file_column_mapping, inplace=True)
        if len(params["names"]) != total_columns:
            missing_columns = [file_column_mapping[c] for c in file_columns - set(params["names"])]
            # add the missing columns to the dataframe
            df[[*missing_columns]] = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(missing_columns)], index=df.index)
        fpath, fname = os.path.split(filepath)
        if not fpath.startswith("gs://"):
            updated_path = os.path.join(fpath, "normalized_with_dd")
            if not os.path.exists(updated_path):
                os.mkdir(updated_path)
            new_path = os.path.join(updated_path, fname)
        else:
            new_path = "/".join([fpath, "normalized_with_dd", fname])
        df.to_csv(new_path, index=False)
    dask_futures = [
        dask.delayed(dask_worker)(file_item, _file_columns, _file_column_mapping, _meta_columns)
        for file_item in file_analysis.items()
    ]
    dask.compute(*dask_futures)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for size, params in local_dirs.items():
        print(f"['{size}_local_analysis_dir_tests'] ({params['items']} files, {params['size']})")
        local_analysis_test_dir_pd(params["directory"])
        local_analysis_test_dir_dd(params["directory"])

    for size, settings in local_dirs.items():
        print(f"['{size}_pre_test_file_cleanup']")
        for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(settings["directory"], '*', '*.csv')):
            os.remove(file)
        print(f"['{size}_local_normalization_dir_tests'] ({settings['items']} files, {settings['size']})")
        files, columns, column_mapping = local_analysis_test_dir_pd(settings["directory"])

        local_normalization_plain_with_pd(files, columns, column_mapping, {})
        local_normalization_plain_with_dd(files, columns, column_mapping, {})

    for size, settings in remote_dirs.items():
        print(f"['{size}_remote_analysis_dir_tests'] ({settings['items']} files, {settings['size']})")
        _, _, _ = remote_analysis_test_dir_pd(settings["directory"])
        files, columns, column_mapping = remote_analysis_test_dir_dd(settings["directory"])

        print(f"['{size}_remote_normalization_dir_tests'] ({settings['items']} files, {settings['size']})")
        normalization_plain_with_pd(files, columns, column_mapping, {})
        normalization_plain_with_dd(files, columns, column_mapping, {})
```

**Conclusions thus far:**

- `local_analysis` is fastest with `pandas.from_csv`, based against:

  - a  single file of                343 MB (  0.0210 sec using `pandas` VS   0.5141 sec using `dask`)
  - a  small  dir  of      8 files/ 1.12 GB (  0.1263 sec using `pandas` VS   0.1357 sec using `dask`)
  - a  medium dir  of    474 files/ 2.03 GB (  3.2991 sec using `pandas` VS   3.7717 sec using `dask`)
  - an xlarge dir  of 13,361 files/46.30 GB (131.5941 sec using `pandas` VS 132.6982 sec using `dask`)
- `local_normalization` is fastest with `pandas.from_csv`, based against:

  - a   small dir  of      8 files/ 1.12 GB (  61.2338 sec using `pandas` VS   62.2033 sec using `dask`)
  - a  medium dir  of    474 files/ 2.03 GB ( 136.8900 sec using `pandas` VS  132.7574 sec using `dask`)
  - an xlarge dir  of 13,361 files/46.30 GB (3166.0797 sec using `pandas` VS 3265.4251 sec using `dask`)
- `remote_analysis` is fastest with `dask.delayed`, based against:

  - a  small  dir  of      8 files/ 1.12 GB (   8.6728 sec using `pandas` VS    6.0795 sec using `dask`)
  - a  medium dir  of    474 files/ 2.03 GB ( 149.7931 sec using `pandas` VS   37.3509 sec using `dask`)
- `remote_normalization` is fastest with `dask.delayed`, based against:

  - a  small  dir  of      8 files/ 1.12 GB (1758.1562 sec using `pandas` VS 1431.9895 sec using `dask`)
  - medium and xlarge datasets not benchmarked yet
- **NOTE:** `dask` tests utilize `pandas.from_csv` inside `dask.delayed()` calls to gain maximum time reduction

Comment: I think this line is your biggest bottleneck: `self.__gs_bucket.blob(blob_path).upload_from_string`. Network operation is really slow, particularly if you have to upload 12k small files. May be write the normalized frames into one big temporary file and upload it at the end? If you need to keep them as 12k separate files on Google Big Blob Storage, zip them up and make 1 upload. Uploading one big file is always faster than several small ones

Comment: I don't have any well formed suggestions...but if efficiency is the goal, have you considered using Spark/PySpark rather than Dask/Python? I'm not too familiar with Google's cloud environment, but in AWS, I'd probably solve this with reading the files from S3 into an EMR cluster.

Comment: Do the input files need to stay a `.csv`? I'm wondering if switching over to something like a `.parquet` would speed things up since you wouldn't have to parse columns/infer types?

Comment: I have to stick with python and they need to remain in their original format (`.csv`). Keep in mind, I'm not only looking for advice on reducing upload time to a Google bucket (I haven't even benchmark tested the bucket upload yet), but I'm also looking to utilize every possible way to reduce the actual processing of the dataframes.

Comment: @CodeDifferent the files cannot be combined unfortunately. In order to overcome server space limitations, coupled with any troubleshooting efforts that would need to pinpoint specific files and their original format combining the files is a non-starter. That's why I've been looking at the parallel operations.

Answer (score 1):

Like Code Different said, the `upload_from_string` bit takes a while. Have you considered writing them to Google BigQuery as opposed to saving them as .csv files in a bucket? I found that faster for my purpose.

Comment: They are ultimately ingested into bigquery at a later point, but they need to be uploaded to a Google bucket first. While I recognize `upload_from_string` is a bottleneck when using the Google storage option of the class, I'm still left with the local processing taking as long as it does. Which is why I'm hoping someone can offer a solution utilizing a combination of the three pieces I've mentioned: `dask`, `ThreadPool`s, and `ProcessPools`. Using those should at least cut the save/upload time by a factor of 8 [cores] (network-permitting).

Answer (score 1):

The `delayed` API might be suitable here. The class you provided is rather elaborate, but this is the rough pattern that might work for this case:

```py
import dask

@dask.delayed
def analyze_one_file(file_name):
    # use the code you run on a single file here
    return dict(skiprows=skiprows, names=headers, dtype=dict.fromkeys(headers, str))

# form delayed computations
delayed_values = [analyze_one_file(filepath) for filepath in files_to_analyze]

# execute the delayed computations
results = dask.compute(delayed_values)

# now results will be a list of dictionaries (or whatever
# the delayed function returns)

# apply similar wrapping to normalize_files loop
```

It might be that there is a more efficient ETL procedure for your case, but this is situation-specific, so assuming that iterating over the files to discover number of rows to skip is necessary, then wrapping things up with `delayed` is probably sufficient to reduce the df processing times by the core multiple.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already benchmarked this approach and it's equivalent to using a plain `pandas` approach. I'm updating my question with the current benchmarks and functions I have used.